# Variables en directiva ng-repeat Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, firebase

¿Con la directiva `ng-repeat` puedo almacenar dos variables distintas?

Ejemplo:

```
ng-repeat="valor1 in valores1 & valor2 in valores2"
```

Tengo problemas para obtener el `key`de mi cadena en Firebase 3 y quiero extraer la `key`. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    var query = firebase.database().ref("path").orderByKey();
    query.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key; console.log($scope.key);
        var childData = childSnapshot.val(); 
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.coupons = snapshot.val();
        });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomando en cuenta la documentación de ngRepeat: 
 https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

No se permiten utilizar dos colecciones en la directiva ng-repeat, pero lo que puedes hacer es lo siguientes.

```
Coleccion1=Key;
Coleccion2=coins;
```

De esta forma cundo realices el ng-repeat sobre la coleccion1 vas a poder obtener informacion de las dos colecciones, si tienen alguna relación con el key. Par extraer datos de la segunda coleccion seria:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Coleccion1>
  <h2>coleccion2[item.key].value</h2>
</div>
```

Otro ejemplo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384072/ng-repeat-objects-relationship

Comment: Muchas gracias colega! Me tomo poco menos de 2 horas comprender el concepto jaja. Ahora el problema se presenta en lo siguiente:

`var ref = firebase.database().ref("coupons");
  ref.on("value", function(dataSnapshot) {
    dataSnapshot.forEach(function(couponSnapshot) {
      var key = [];
      key = couponSnapshot.key;
      var coupon = [];
      coupon = couponSnapshot.val();
      coupon.key = key;
      $scope.coupons = coupon;
      console.log($scope.coupons);
    });
  });`

No logro hacer que se vea de forma correcta la variable coupons por medio del scope en la vista

Comment: Que problema te presenta?

Comment: No muestra los elementos en el scope cuando lo llamo al ng-repeat en el html.

Comment: Revisa este ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/maikolEstevezPena/e05cw13t/

Comment: Te pudiera ayudar mejor si me muestras el objeto que te devuelve la base de datos.

Comment: Le hice una modificación al ejemplohttps://jsfiddle.net/maikolEstevezPena/e05cw13t/2/

Comment: Necesite transformar esto:

var ref = firebase.database().ref("coupons");
  ref.on("value", function(dataSnapshot) {
    dataSnapshot.forEach(function(couponSnapshot) {
      var key;
      key = couponSnapshot.key;
      var coupon;
      coupon = couponSnapshot.val();
      coupon = {coupon};
      console.log("Firebase: ", coupon);
    });
  });

A una estructura similar a esta: http://prntscr.com/dbdvsj

Comment: Nunca he trabajado con fireBase, que es lo que tiene dataSnapshot, cual es la estructura de ese array?